# Is there a specification defines INBOX as the primary folder?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jakarta-mail, imap, lotus-domino

I just play with emails recently. An application downloads email from mail server with apache-camel-mail component via `IMAP` protocol and do some magic with the email body.

The problem I observe is about primary email folder name on Lotus notes email server. It supposed to be **INBOX** but actually it is **Inbox**.

My question is...

*Is there a specification for IMAP or email in general to define the primary folder as **INBOX**? Or I can hypothetically used in my fresh new mail server primary inbox name like **1nB0x** with no harm and still be compliant to IMAP spec.*

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) (IMAP version 4rev1):

> The case-insensitive mailbox name INBOX is a special name reserved to
> mean "the primary mailbox for this user on this server".  The
> interpretation of all other names is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Well, it should be `case-insensitive` thought.